# Socket io send data from one application to another

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets, socket.io

I am trying to share data between *customer* and *agent* using web socket. The *customer* and *agent* are 2 separate applications and socket.io being used to pass data between them. I am able to pass data from the *customer* application to *socket server*, but failing to pass that data data to the *agent* application.

Initially I was getting CORS error for connecting to socket server from agent side, but when I added agent url the CORS issue was solved but still data was not received. To add customer url would be from `example.com` and and agent application will be on a subdomain of `example.com`, `sd.example.com` . For applications I am using React, where as NodeJS is used for creating the server. Customer application (running on Port `3000`)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"))
  }, []);

  const handleClick = () => {
    socket.emit("user", {
      name: "Souvik Banerjee"
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Socket server (run on port `5000`)

```js
import { createServer } from "http";
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const httpServer = createServer();
const io = new Server(httpServer, {
    cors: {
        origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:3001']
    }
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("user", (user) => {
        // this console log is getting printed
        console.log('user', user);

        socket.emit('newUser', {
            user,
            socketId: socket.id
        })
    })
});

httpServer.listen(5000, () => {
    console.log('5000')
});
```

Agent application (running on port `3001`)

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { io } from 'socket.io-client';

function App() {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  const [user, setUser] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"))
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket?.on("newUser", (data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      setUser(data);
    })
  }, [socket]);

  return (
    <div>
      Hello, {user.name || 'anonymous'}!
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Github : https://github.com/souviiik/only-socket-poc

Comment: Why you used `?` in `socket?.on("newUser", (data) => {
      console.log('data', data);
      setUser(data);
    })
`?

Comment: Socket is undefined initially, so cannot read property of undefined issue was thrown.

Comment: Try to replace by  `http://localhost:3000` in `useEffect(()=> {setSocket(io("http://localhost:5000"))}, []);`

Comment: Bro, that did not work, can you please download the code from github and check?

Comment: Instead of `socket.emit()`, use `io.emit()`